# Go can't find my local package

Tags: go

I am getting the following error when trying to build a go project I am working on.

```
cannot find package "github.com/user/projectname/models" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/user/projectname/models (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/username/go/src/github.com/user/projectname/models (from $GOPATH)
```

This error is confusing me as the package is located in the directory from goroot. I have 3 go files there with models defined in them. When I run 'go build' or 'go install' in the models directory, no errors are returned. I am new to go and believe I must be missing something simple. I am using a mac and my github username directory shows up as github.com:user instead of github.com/username. Could that make a difference?

Class to import model snippet:

```
package dal

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"

    "github.com/user/projectname/models"
)
```

Model class:

```
package models

import "time"

//Album of an artist.
type Album struct {
    ID          int       `json:"id"`
    Title       string    `json:"title"`
    ArtistID    int       `json:"artist_id"`
    ReleaseDate time.Time `json:"date"`
}
```

[Directory Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euaUC.png)

Comment: You wrote `This error is confusing me as the package is located in this directory` - which one of them is "this directory"? And perhaps double and triple check the actual paht :)

Comment: make sure your project base directory is in `$GOPATH`

Comment: Your error does not match your code: Your code imports  github.com/username/projectname/models (**username**) while your error stats it cannot find github.com/user/projectname/models (**user**). Just fix your setup. Your package is not there.

Comment: I have updated the post, I used user instead of username when removing my github username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed my directory structure and the package now imports. Previously, my folders were named as followed src->github.com, github.com/username. I have since reworked it to src->github.com->username. Moving the folders like this allows the project to be found easily.

The official [go documentation](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) makes it unclear that this is the intended structure. However, upon looking at [the github code layout](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GitHubCodeLayout) it becomes clear.